# Automate Streaming API with Python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

How to consume response chunk-ed data from Streaming API using Python.

Tried with "request" module but after sending request to API, python script hangs with no response written over console.

Comment: `requests` definitely supports chunked Transfer-Encoding. Have you tried the same request with curl? What API, is it public?

Comment: Yes, tried with 'Curl' it works but API Response is never-ending looking out for a solution that can get response-store it somewhere file/variable-analyse response. Preferably in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use ["streaming requests"](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests).

Set the `stream` parameter to `True` when calling `requests.get()`. The request will not block, and you can iterate over the streamed data using the `iter_content()` method of the `Response` object:

```
response = requests.get('http://server/stream-forever', stream=True)
for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=10):
    print data
```

This will read the response content in chunks of 10 bytes and print it to the console.